# How can I display a font awesome glyph in XAML/C#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, font-awesome, glyph

I have tried many things in Visual Studio, but I still can not display a glyph.

1. Do I need to add a NuGet package? Which?
2. Do I need a 'using ...;' in C#?
3. Do I need a 'xmlns:...' in XAML?
4. Should I display it with a "Label"?

I know in HTML, you just add a class to your element.  But I am stumped in XAML.
(It's cross-platform, right?)

This should a simple thing but I can not get any answers to function.  Please provide an answer if you can do this and answer all points.

Comment: please learn to use google - https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Iconize

Comment: @Flot2011 I can't seem to get this working. Still get a red underline whenever I have 'FontAwsome ...'.  What's the secret?

Comment: @Jason Is this also form UWP?

Comment: @Flot2011link is for WinForms, not Xamarin Forms.  They are completely different things.  If you want to know what platforms Iconize supports, try reading the docs

Comment: Use this url to get your desired unicode as c# classes: https://github.com/fzany/Font-Awesome-Cheat-Charp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a correct [plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize) for Xamarin.Forms. This plugin not only has FontAwesome Font.

According to [this example in github](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Iconize/Samples) you must do the following:

```xml
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <iconize:IconLabel FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Key}" TextColor="Green" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
</StackLayout>
```

**[UPDATE]**

On request from user3247130 I leave the complete example:

From Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio, install the following packages:

- Xam.Plugin.Iconize
- Xam.Plugin.Iconize.FontSwesome
- Xam.FormsPlugin.Iconize

In the Android project, `MainActivity` class, OnCreate() method add:

```
FormsPlugin.Iconize.Droid.IconControls.Init(Resource.Id.toolbar);
Plugin.Iconize.Iconize.With(new Plugin.Iconize.Fonts.FontAwesomeModule());
```

In the iOS project, `AppDelegate` class, FinishedLaunching() method, add similar lines:

```
FormsPlugin.Iconize.iOS.IconControls.Init();
Plugin.Iconize.Iconize.With(new Plugin.Iconize.Fonts.FontAwesomeModule());
```

Also, in iOS project, info.plist add

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>     
    <string>iconize-fontawesome.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Now, in your `XAML` where your have your toolbar, in tag, add

```
<ContentPage ...
xmlns:iconize="clr-namespace:FormsPlugin.Iconize;assembly=FormsPlugin.Iconize">
```

and

```
<iconize:IconLabel Text="fa-search"  />
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

This plugin has an issue on UWP platform.
To run this plugin on UWP platform follow these steps:

First, create a folder called `Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome.UWP` into `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\xam.plugin.iconize.fontawesome‌​\2.0.0.29-beta\lib\U‌​AP10\`

Second, create another folder called `Assets` into `Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome.UWP` folder

Third create anoother folder called `Fonts` into `Assets` folder

And finally copy [iconize-fontawesome.ttf](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/raw/master/Iconize/Fonts/FontAwesome/iconize-fontawesome.ttf) file (you shouldn't change their name).

> Additionally, you have to add a **Fonts** folder in the **Assets** folder in your UWP project and then paste the same ttf file
>
> This is not necessary on Android or iOS it is only a issue of the UWP platform

Comment: Could you create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) to be able to see your source code?

Comment: Which platform are you deploying to?

Comment: Oh right!! This is a UWP platform issue. To solve it you must copy the file tff ([download here](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/raw/master/Iconize/Fonts/FontAwesome/iconize-fontawesome.ttf)) in this path:
 
**%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\xam.plugin.iconize.fontawesome\2.0.0.29-beta\lib\UAP10\Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome.UWP\Assets\Fonts**

Comment: It is very likely that you do not have the **Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome.UWP\Assets\Fonts** folder so you should go to **%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\xam.plugin.iconize.fontawesome\2.0.0.29 -beta\lib\UAP10** and create those folders, then you can copy the ttf file

Comment: This is not necessary on Android or iOS it is only a issue of the UWP platform.

Comment: Oh! I forgot ... you also have to add a **Fonts** folder in the **Assets** folder in your UWP project and then paste the same ttf file

Comment: download it from here: https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/raw/master/Iconize/Fonts/FontAwesome/iconize-fontawesome.ttf you shouldn't change their name

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough reputation to move to chat... So I deleted all my comments, I guess that only you can delete yours.
The icons are appearing but I used <Label Font="FontAwesome" Text="&#xf095;" /> - this is what I tried before.  Again when I put that iconize:IconLabel tag in it goes to debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Plugin.Glypher](https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.Glypher) it has Font Awesome 5 Free/Pro and WeatherIcons support.

- [Plugin.Glypher.FontAwesome5Free](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Glypher.FontAwesome5Free/)
- [Plugin.Glypher.FontAwesome5Pro](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Glypher.FontAwesome5Pro/)
- [Plugin.Glypher.WeatherIcons](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Glypher.WeatherIcons/)

```cs
xmlns:fontAwesome5Free="clr-namespace:Plugin.Glypher.FontAwesome5Free;assembly=Plugin.Glypher.FontAwesome5Free"
xmlns:glypher="clr-namespace:Plugin.Glypher;assembly=Plugin.Glypher"

<Label glypher:FontGlyph.Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome5Free:GlyphList.Fab_Bluetooth}"
       FontSize="Large"
       TextColor="CornflowerBlue" />

<Button glypher:FontGlyph.Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome5Free:GlyphList.Fab_Bitcoin}"
        FontSize="Large"
        TextColor="IndianRed" />

<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <FontImageSource Size="32" 
                         Color="Orange" 
                         glypher:FontGlyph.Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome5Free:GlyphList.Far_Bell_Slash}" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

It's all in shared code. But it depends on Xamarin.Forms (>= 3.6.0.344457)