# FontAwesome in Xamarin forms UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, font-awesome, xamarin.uwp

I have a Custom renderer working in Android with Fontawesome.
I was following this guide [using font awesome in UWP](https://www.devdashboard.com/280/using-font-icons-for-xamarin-forms)
With a custom Label type to try to get Fontawesome working in UWP.

```
public class FontAwesomeLabel: Xamarin.Forms.Label    {
    public FontAwesomeLabel()        {
        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
      {
           case Device.UWP:
                FontFamily = @"/Assets/FontAwesome.otf#FontAwesome";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The fonts
 [image: FontAwesome Asset]
were loaded as both ttf and otf. I have tried both types.
They Assest fonts have build action "Content"

```
mainView.Children.Add( new FontAwesomeLabel()
      {Text = FaConstPool.FASearch ,FontSize = 40});

public static string FASearch = "\uf002";
```

Only works on Android and not in UWP

I see a strange box and not the expected Fontawesome icon as for Android.

Any ideas what i have done wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to the problem  turned out to be in UWP, use the correct font family name.
 **Font Awesome 5 Free Solid**
and not just "FontAwesome"

```
 // FontFamily = @"/Assets/FontAwesome.otf#FontAwesome"; // incorrect font family name
    FontFamily = @"/Assets/Fonts/FontAwesome.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid";
```

For anyone interested in details:
I downloaded a font editor to check the internal font name and font family name.  I made the mistake of code copying blog posts that used values from similar/older fonts. See image for actual content.

There are 2 types of solution I got to work:
1) A custom control in shared code /.netStandard Common project.
2) a custom renderer

**Solution 1: Custom Label**

```
public class FontAwesomeLabel: Xamarin.Forms.Label
{
    public FontAwesomeLabel()
    {
        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
           case Device.UWP:
             // make sure the correct font family name is used. Check in a font editor
               this.FontFamily = @"/Assets/Fonts/FontAwesome.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: Customer renderer on Standard Control**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(FontAwesomeLabelRenderer))]
namespace Oxando.UWP.CustomRenderers
{
public class FontAwesomeLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            // on UWP be sure use the Font Family name.
            // get a font editor and check the name, if it doesnt match UWP wont load it
            if (FontAwesomeUtil.CheckIsFA(e.NewElement.Text))
            {
                Control.FontFamily = new FontFamily("/Assets/Fonts/FontAwesome.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid");
            }
        }
    }
}
internal static class FontAwesomeUtil
{
    public static bool CheckIsFA(string text)
    {
        if (text.Length == 0) return false;
        if (text.Length > 1 || text[0] < 0xf000) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Actual internal names as shown in Font editor 
[image: Font Awesome 5 download as of Jan 2018]

Comment: thx  CoCaIceDew your right. I was trying to record the answer for others and forgot to mark as answered.

Answer (score 2):

The correct path to add a font on UWP is `/Assets/Fonts/FontAwesome.ttf#FontAwesome` it seems you have to add the `Fonts` folder.

Like this:

[image]

Additionally you can use [Iconize plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize) and check this answer:

[How can I display a font awesome glyph in XAML/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46063938/how-can-i-display-a-font-awesome-glyph-in-xaml-c/46079486#46079486)

Comment: I tried moving Font to a directory. No luck.  Not sure why that would be necessary.

Comment: Maybe you should use [Iconize plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize) for this purpose.

Comment: I installed Iconize.UWP and would use it if i knew how. I wasnt able to figure how to use it in code behind to set a custom label type.